# Create a Live Stream highlight via the YouTube API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I know you can create and upload highlights using the web UI, but is there a way to programmatically create a highlight via the API (or other) during a live broadcast?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no API exposed to create a highlight from a live event.  The only way to create a highlight is through the Web UI (like you said) using Stream Now Beta or a scheduled Live Event.  As an alternative, you could always programmatically set up the live event and manually go into the Live Control Room to create the event.

After speaking with a YouTube Dev Relations rep, I believe exposing an API for highlights was on the roadmap after exposing APIs for chat, which were made public last week (see the Live Streaming API's [revision history](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/revision_history)).

Comment: A year and a bit later, there's still no exposed API for this. Do you/does your contact know if this is still in-the-works?

Comment: Hey @Jamie, sadly there still does not appear to be an API exposed for this.